# Adding to html so previously defined functions will work

Tags: jquery

i have this document:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div id="preview">
      <p>test</p>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And i have this codes:

```
$("p").mouseover(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
});
$("p").mouseout(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","lightgray");
});

function add(){ 
    $("#preview").append("<p id="test">test2</p>");
}
```

The problem is, that the `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions only work on the `<p>` that i added on the html, and not on the `<p>` i appended through the jquery.
 What can i do so the jquery appended `<p>` will be able to call mouseover and mouseout too?

Comment: use jQuery's on() instead.

Comment: In future please make use of the **search** function. This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `.on()` to add the handlers. Somenthing like this

```
$('body').on('mouseover', 'p', function() { ...
```

This will add an event handler to the body, but will first filter by the second parameter before the function is actually called. This way all `<p>` tags, current and future, will have the event handler working.

For full doc, read the API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation via jQuery's `.on()` function, which will apply an event to a selector even if there is dynamic content, like this:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', 'p', function() {

});
```

Note: This instructs jQuery to look for any `<p>` tags in the `<body>` (now or in the future) of your HTML and when they generate a `mouseover` event, then the content in the `function()` callback gets executed.